# Julia: Turn Vector into multiple m x n matrices without a loop

Tags: julia

Let's say I have a vector `V`, and I want to either turn this vector into multiple `m x n` matrices, or get multiple `m x n` matrices from this Vector V.
For the most basic example: Turn `V = collect(1:75)` into 3 `5x5` matrices.

As far as I am aware this can be done by first using reshape `reshape(V, 5, :)` and then looping through it. Is there a better way in Julia without using a loop?

If possible, a solution that can easily change between row-major and column-major results is preferrable.

Comment: Do you want the 3 matrices "blockwise" (`reshape(1:25, ...)` etc.), or strided? `collect(eachslice(reshape(V, 3,5, 5), dims = 1))` gives something of the desired shape, but maybe not what you want.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want a loop? Fwiw I generally find loops to be the most readable form of expressing these transformations.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the request for row-major results, I actually never worked in row-major arrays and can't find anything with a quick search. I suppose `transpose` takes a column-major array and returns a view representing a row-major array, but it's not the same as making a row-major array right off the bat.

Comment: @phipsgabler Shouldn't it be `collect(eachslice(reshape(V, 5,5,:); dims=3))`?

Comment: Maybe, the dims argument always confuses me...

Comment: @NilsGudat It's just that as of my understanding, it should be possible to do it in Julia, it's not that I want to avoid loops in all cases. Turns out `reshape(V, 5, 5, :)` is basically what I want. I posted some follow up questions under the answer of @NaphatAmundsen. Also what is the difference between `transpose` and `permutedims` (which I used so far to switch between column-major and row-major).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL:DR**

```
m, n, n_matrices = 4, 2, 5
V = collect(1:m*n*n_matrices)
V = reshape(V, m, n, :)
V = permutedims(V, [2,1,3])
display(V)
```

**From my limited knowledge about Julia:**

When doing `V = collect(1:m*n)`, you initialize a contiguous array in memory. From `V` you wish to create a container of `m` by `n` matrices. You can achieve this by doing `reshape(V, m, n, :)`, then you can access the first matrix with `V[:,:,1]`. The "container" in this case is just another array (thus you have a three dimensional array), which in this case we interpret as "an array of matrices" (but you could also interpret it as a box). You can then transpose every matrix in your array by swapping the first two dimensions like this: `permutedims(V, [2,1,3])`.

**How this works**

From what I understand; n-dimensional arrays in Julia are contiguous arrays in memory when you don't do any "skipping" (e.g. `V[1:2:end]`).  For example the `2 x 4` matrix `A`:

```
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8
```

is in memory just `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`. You simply interpret the data in a specific way, where the first two numbers makes up the first column, then the second two numbers makes the next column so on so forth. The `reshape` function simply specifies how you want to interpret the data in memory. So if we did `reshape(A, 4, 2)` we basically interpret the numbers in memory as "the first four values makes the first column, the second four values makes the second column", and we would get:

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

We are basically doing the same thing here, but with an extra dimension.

From my observations it also seems to be that `permutedims` in this case reallocates memory. Also, feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

**Old answer:**

I don't know much about Julia, but in Python using NumPy I would have done something like this:

```py
reshape(V, :, m, n)
```

EDIT: As @BatWannaBe states, the result is technically one array (but three dimensional). You can always interpret a three dimensional array as a container of 2D arrays, which from my understanding is what you ask for.

Comment: Technically speaking, `reshape(1:75, :, 5, 5)` makes a 3x5x5 ReshapedArray, but I'm pretty sure this is what OP wants. To make 3 separate 5x5 instances, there must be a loop at some level.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that OP wants an iterable of `(m, n)` sized arrays. For NumPy at least, a simple solution would be to do it like in my answer.

Comment: I gave this a try in Julia, had to turn it around, `V = reshape(V, 5, 5, :)` looks promising. After which I can address them with `V[:, :, 1]` , `V[:, :, 2]` etc.
A few questions: 

- Why does this work?
- If I have a single matrix `A`, result from `reshape`, I can switch to "row-major" by using `permutedims(A)`, is it possible to apply this to all the matrices I get from `reshape(V, 5, 5, :)` somehow in one step?

Comment: @JessicaNowak Hello again. I have finally gotten some time to try out Julia, and I have now updated my answer to address your additional questions.